# IndexOf in Velocity report?

Tags: javascript, velocity, indexof

Is there some equivalent of javascripts indexOf in Velocity?
I want to test whether some string is contained within another string but I can't find the proper string operator for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Velocity allows you to use all Java methods available in your objects. So just write as if it was Java:

```
$string1.indexOf($string2)
```